# How to mix fixed and % width in responsive web design?

Tags: responsive-design

I have simple web page which consist of two columns : sidebar and content. There is no problem if both columns are dynamic but the width of sidebar must be fixed and the content width should be dynamic depending on browser width.

I don't know how to calculate the width of the columns.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the sidebar *really* have to be fixed in size, and why?

Comment: Because it contains adsense ads that have fixed size

Comment: Ah, well that does make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7gKuR/)**

```
#sidebar { 
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    overflow: auto; 
 /* trigger a block formatting context (this fills remaining horizontal width) */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you're looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ekVJe/

What I've done is float the sidebar left, and then give the content a left-margin that's equivalent to the width of the sidebar:

```
#sidebar { 
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is similar with previous one.